# Limit the number of digits in integer?

Tags: python, integer, odoo

Is there a way to limit number of digits in integer in OpenERP like you can in char type?
I need field that would only let you enter max two digits.

For example with char, you can do this:

```
from openerp.osv import fields

'char_field': fields.char(size=2),
```

Then if you try to enter more than two symbols, it won't write it.

But if I create integer field:

```
'integer_field': fields.integer(),
```

It will let me write any number of digits I want.

Comment: Use something like `len(str(123))` to check the length of an integer (no idea what openerp is though)?

Comment: Yeah I know I can check it with something after integer was entered (in create/write methods). But I would like to prevent that altogether. Like with char type you just don't need to check if length exceeds size limit, because it simply does not let you enter more symbols.

Comment: @senthilnathang Yeah this might be the best possible approach. But there is one delicate matter. It's that first time record is created it should let enter any information user wants (it's because of clients specific work of nature. That user can be called anytime and   he should leave work-space immediately. So he should be able to save that record). And that's why I'm looking for ways to prevent wrong inputs before hand, but letting creation of record anyway.

Comment: then you have to check with create and write methods to validate field value

Comment: @senthilnathang Well that actually would be the same as it would also prevent from creating/writing. Validation occurs when confirmation button is pressed. So I guess I can implement such validation checks on confirmation. The only problem is, confirmation method is already full of all kinds of checks.

Comment: @Andrius in create method let it be allowed,but  do validation say len() in write method

Comment: @senthilnathang its' still not a good solution. Because user might create and then edit/write multiple times before confirmation.

Comment: @Andrius so what is your exact requirement ?

Comment: @senthilnathang I written it in a question. Asking if its possible to limit same way as you can with char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `_constraint` to check the value of your integer and raise an exception if it is not in your desired range.

Check this [blog post about how to create a constraint](http://atulone.blogspot.pt/2012/07/constraints-in-openerp.html).

Comment: Forgot about constraints. Well I think there is no better approach for limiting digits in integer than this. So this should do. Thanks.